# Satellite velocity from km/s to arcsec

Tags: python, velocity, astropy, skyfield

I can't change the current satellite velocity from km/s units to arcsec units. This is a snippet of my code:

```
from astropy import units as u


def check_the_satellites_current_velocity(self, available_satellites):
    satellites_velocity = {}
    for satellite in available_satellites:
        self.choose_satellite_by_name(satellite)
        pos = (self.satellite - self.bluffton).at(self.t)
        _, _, the_range, _, _, range_rate = pos.frame_latlon_and_rates(self.bluffton)
        # satellites_velocity[satellite] = array2string(range_rate.km_per_s, precision=2)
        satellites_velocity[satellite] = array2string(range_rate.to(u.arcsec), precision=5)
    return satellites_velocity
```

The commented line works fine. I have the value in km/s. But I can't convert to arcsec units. I think my import is wrong. I have tried on few ways and no results.

There is a skyfield documentation: https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/api-units.html

When I run this code I have error:

> astropy.units.core.UnitConversionError: 'AU / d' (speed/velocity) and 'arcsec' (angle) are not convertible

How I can get the satellite velocity in arcsec units?

Comment: Well, did you know that the relationship between the speed and the angle depends on the altitude?

Comment: The import is not wrong.

Comment: @mkrieger1 no.. I am new in this subject. Can you show me how to get the satellite velocity in arcsec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're using [`frame_latlon_and_rates`](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/api-position.html#skyfield.positionlib.ICRF.frame_latlon_and_rates) already returns latitudinal and longitudinal angular velocities which you're ignoring.

Comment: you have right. That was my unknowledge. Function frame_latlon_and_rates returns lat_angle_rate and that value can be represent by arcsec. Thanks!